# Very slow scrolling in vim's split screen

Tags: vim

When I scroll in vim using <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> or mouse wheel it is very responsive and fast, but as soon as I open a new buffer in split screen scrolling becomes very slow/delayed. It manly occurs in very large files (1000+ Lines), even if the second buffer in split screen is empty.

I reproduced this using different terminals. I also tried to use `ttyfast` and `lazyredraw` but none of them change anything.

If I start vim with `-u NONE` it is the same, just not as noticeable.

What is the big difference in running vim with and without split screen in terms of scrolling and redrawing the screen?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the problem only occurs in vertical split. Horizontal split works fine!

**EDIT2:**

The behavior only appears using terminal version of vi/vim. As soon as i start gVim with the same configuration as vim everything works like a charm, even in vertical split. I found someone with a similar problem in an other forum. He got an answer what the problem may be, but not how to fix it. The answer was:

```
That's because the application has to repaint the screen rather than actually
scrolling (since it cannot rely on the left/right halves of the display
to scroll at the same rate).
```

**EDIT3:**

I'am running Ubuntu 13.10 - 64 Bit.
My computer specs are:

- Intel Core i7-4770K
- GeForce GTX 760 (proprietary driver nvidia-319)
- 16 GB Ram

Here the output of `vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 12 2013 00:23:33)
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
```

Comment: @r3mus Hi, how could you make the j and k displaying like this? It's cool. :-)

Comment: @Unheilig `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`

Comment: Is the new buffer large ? Do tabs behave in the same way ?

Comment: Just click on the edit button...

Comment: it is strange if it occurred even if you started with `-u NONE`. can you tell which OS and which vim version are you using? also can you try to open an empty split buffer? which file did you opened in the new buffer? type? size?

Comment: What platform are you running on? This performance can actually be dependent on video card drivers, believe it or not...

Comment: @user1281385 the old buffer is a large file, the new buffer can be NerdTree or TagBar for example. That is actually my Problem. Because i like to have TagBar open when working in my code, but its very annoying because of the delay. As soon as i close TagBar everything is good. Tabs don't behave that way.

Comment: @Kent the same behavior occurs if i open an empty buffer in split screen. But i just realized that problem only appears in vertical split, horizontal split is no problem at all. The file is a large *.cpp with a lot of comments (~1000 lines)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i added my operation system and my computer specs to the question

Comment: Does the large file have long lines?  Does `:set nowrap` make a difference?

Comment: @benjifisher the line are approximately 80 characters long. `:set nowrap` doesnt make a difference. But it was a good idea. I really hope that it would change the behavior, since it only appears in vertical split and not in horizontal.

Comment: Maybe you are running a 32-bit vim on a 64-bit OS?  I have access to a Ubuntu 12.4 system, and do not see anything like what you describe.  There are a few differences:  I have vim 7.3.429, and it is a non-GUI version.  Can you try installing an alternative version?  Or maybe you already have another version installed as /usr/bin/vi.

Comment: @benjifisher i'm using non-GUI version as well. Just tried gVim and surprisingly it works like a charm in vertical split. So it seems like its a problem with the terminal and vi/vim.

Comment: I used vim in a terminal, over ssh.  Did you check `:version` in terminal and GUI to make sure they were the same binary?

Comment: 1) are you by any chance using a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux? 2) if not, have you tried this in a different type of terminal (like xterm, uxterm, etc.)?

Comment: Does `:set noruler` help at all? I guess it wouldn't when starting with `-u NONE`.

Comment: Have you tried `:syntax off`? I recall a slow scroll issue I had some years ago that was mainly due to the syntax painting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have answered the original question:

```
That's because the application has to repaint
the screen rather than actually scrolling
```

This is what I do When it scroll *slow* for me, not necessarily because the splitting, I'd try to use: `22j` instead of `j`, `22` can be any number, it let `vim` do shifting rather then calculate the scrolling for each `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question has been answered I would like to add my solution which seems to work for me running Vim 7.4.52 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) instead for vertically splitting the terminal window and running independent instances of vim in each emulated terminal. Coupled with [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator), which allows for seamless navigation between vim- and tmux splits, the experience is largely the same, but without stuttering while scrolling.

The only thing I miss is the ability to yank/paste from one buffer to another, but surely this is solvable as well.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's still slow when using vertical tmux splits instead of vertical vim splits